# How to Resolve Missing IAM Service Account Issue in Google Cloud Composer 2 Environment Setup?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, terraform-provider-gcp

I am encountering an issue while trying to set up a Google Cloud Composer 2 environment. Upon creation, I received an error indicating missing IAM roles in a specific Service Account: `service-905653009305@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. However, upon checking in the IAM section of my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) console, I couldn't locate this service account anymore.

It seems like the Service Account mentioned in the error message has been removed or doesn't exist anymore in the IAM section. Hence, I'm unsure how to proceed with resolving this issue, especially since I can't recreate the same Service Account.

The specific IAM role that seems to be missing is `roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext`.

How can I effectively resolve this issue and proceed with setting up the Google Cloud Composer 2 environment without the mentioned Service Account? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
ERROR:


The issue may be caused by missing IAM roles in the following Service Accounts:
- service-905653009305@cloudcomposer-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com in project 
905653009305 is missing role roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext

The list of missing roles is generated without checking individual permissions in IAM 
custom roles. If any of the Service Accounts above uses custom IAM roles, its 
permissions may be sufficient and a corresponding warning may be ignored.*
```

Comment: Did you try to go to the IAM page, click on add member, set the SA email and select the correct role. The SA should exist, it is simply not binded to your project.

Comment: In the Iam page, there is an option on the right top to show the default or per role service accounts. Ticket it and you should be able to see the service account you are mentioning

Answer (score 1):

The service account does not belong to your project but to the `cloudcomposer-accounts` project, managed by Google Cloud. Therefore, you can't delete it.

But you can delete the binding. To restore it, go to the IAM page, add a member to your project, set the cloudcomposer-accounts email and grant the `roles/composer.ServiceAgentV2Ext` role.

Sometimes, disabling and re-enabling the API can also solve the issue.